# Why didn't Jesus allow demons to say he was God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, demons, gospel-of-mark, messianic-secret, demon-possession

After Jesus cast out demons from possessed people, he made sure that these demons didn't reveal his true identity.  Why?

Example from [Mar 1:24-25,34 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%201:24-34&version=NIV):

> <sup>24</sup>“What do you want with us, Jesus of Nazareth? Have you come to destroy us? I know who you are—the Holy One of God!”
>   <sup>25</sup>“Be quiet!” said Jesus sternly. “Come out of him!”
>   ...
>   <sup>34</sup>and Jesus healed many who had various diseases. He also drove out many demons, but he would not let the demons speak because they knew who he was.